# Change titles in sales->orders page in admin panel mageno

Tags: php, magento, ecommerce-sales

I have to change the `Bill to Name` and `Ship to Name` titles in

```
 admin panel->sales->orders page in Magento.
```

But I can't find the page. For this, which page contain these titles?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and answered here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/41929/4997

Most probably this would work for you in this case.

Moreover, you also need to make modifications here:

```
$this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));
```

Uou can change `'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),` to your desired one like `'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('MY CUSTOM FIELD'),`